# Proper use of if else

Tags: pug

UPDATE:
I found a solution, i used inline html, but Im not sure if this is the best practice but its working now.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I am new in Jade templating and I need some help in this simple condition.

I have a **condition** like this:

```
each item, i in items
if ((i % 3) == 0)
  .row
    .item
else
  .item
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
.row
  .item
.item
.item
.row
  .item
.item
.item
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
.row
  .item
  .item
  .item
.row
  .item
  .item
  .item
```

It doesn't matter if I have to change the logic or approach. I just have to achieve the desired output.

Comment: If i starts at 0, then 0%3 == 0 matches so the if is executed. so better to add i!=0 check as well. I do not know what jade is, so may be I am entirely wrong.

Comment: Yeah I think your right. Thanks Arun!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do the indents in an else block continue from the then block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43573633/do-the-indents-in-an-else-block-continue-from-the-then-block)

Answer (score 0):

If `i` starts at `0`, then `0%3 == 0` matches so the `if` is executed. so better to add `i!=0` check as well. I do not know what jade is, so excuse if I am wrong...