# Do the indents in an else block continue from the then block?

Tags: pug

The following Pug script:

```
- data = [ "A", "B", "C", "D" ]
- for (i=0,i<data.length;i++)
-  var even = (i%2)==0
   if even
     .row
       .col #{data[i]}
   else
       .col #{data[i]}
```

produces:

```
<div class="row"> 
   <div class="col">A</div>
</div>
<div class="col">B</div>
<div class="row"> 
   <div class="col">C</div>
</div>
<div class="col">D</div>
```

What I want is:

```
<div class="row"> 
   <div class="col">A</div>
   <div class="col">B</div>
</div>
<div class="row"> 
   <div class="col">C</div>
   <div class="col">D</div>
</div>
```

Why is the indent in the else block not followed?  How do I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pug, by nature, doesn't allow that kind of "extra" indentation within the `else` block. To achieve your desired result, you could think about it like this—

```
- var data = [ "A", "B", "C", "D" ]

each datum, index in data
  if ((index % 2) == 0)
    .row
      .col #{datum}
      if (data[index + 1])
        .col #{data[index + 1]}
```

—which yields—

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">A</div>
  <div class="col">B</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">C</div>
  <div class="col">D</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although sean's answer is correct it does contain code duplication because you have to specify what you want to do with the item, twice per row. His answer also doesn't scale well for situations where you need more than two items per row.

Instead of using the [i+1] structure by sean's I would suggest using a second loop to find all the items that have to fall into this row. This can be done using the following pattern:

```
- var itemsPerRow = 2; // This can be any positive number
each unused, i in data
  if (i % itemsPerRow == 0)
    .row
      each item, j in data
        if (j - i >= 0 && j - i < itemsPerRow)
          .col
             .. What you want to do with -item- ..
```

The line `if (j - i >= 0 && j - i < itemsPerRow)` makes sure that only the items that actually fall into that row get render.

This avoids code duplication because you only have to type `.. What you want to do with -item- ..` once.

The result looks like this

```
.row
  .col
  .col
.row
  .col
  .col
.row
  .col
  .col
```